# Vi on Xenix: why instead of scroll the line overwrite the current line?

Tags: vi

On linux and old Unix (at&t for example)
when I scroll the line I see the text
on Xenix the current read line is "overwriting"
the screen.
Look at [video](https://vid.me/fljb),you understand what i'm talking about

How to solve? Is it a terminal problem or some option with vi?

Comment: What is the terminal and what is the `TERM` environment variable set to?

Comment: Ansi term on minicom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a problem with your configuration (neither the terminal nor the program).

Connecting through minicom sounds like a serial-port (or modem) connection.  vi is getting the screensize either from some predefined setting for the connection, or it gets it from the terminal description. It has no way to sense the actual screen dimensions.  There are a few usual workarounds:

- use a program (or script) that updates the screensize known to the remote system.  If it is not *too* archaic, it has [`stty`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stty&sektion=1), which would show the size as `rows` and `columns`, e.g., in the output of "stty -a". In less-than-ancient systems, the [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program is good for *that* (but I recall minicom as lacking much of the VT100 features - so that probably would not work).  But even without it, if your `stty` displays those values (wrong perhaps) you can override it, e.g., `stty rows 24`.
- override the program by setting the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` environment variables
- modify the terminal description on the remote machine.  For instance it might be a termcap, where there is something like ":li#40:co:80:".  As a rule, programs that rely upon termcap assume that the proper screensize is in the termcap file.

Comment: Normally vi does not try to figure out the screen size on its own but there are at least two ways of doing so using ANSI terminal codes so one could theoretically create a script that figures out the correct screen size at some point and sets it system-wide.

Comment: The easiest solution was TERM=xterm and export TERM,vi works fine btw i mark answer as correct because is good answer